# A vector space basis for a cyclic module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

I'm reading Artin, and he writes:
[image]

Is the fact that $(w_0,tw_0,\dots,t^{n-1}w_0)$ is a basis for $W$ as a vector space obvious? It didn't seem obvious to me so I wrote a formal proof of this fact, which despite of being elementary is not a two-line proof. So I was wondering (1) whether my proof is fine and (2) whether this fact is obvious from some other considerations which I didn't use.

Proof of the fact that $(w_0,tw_0,\dots,t^{n-1}w_0)$ **generates** $W$.

> Let $w\in W$, so $w=g(t)w_0$ for some $g(t)\in F[t]$. Its preimage
>    under the map $F[t]\to W$ given by $h(t)\mapsto h(t)w_0$ is $g(t)$.
>    The image of $g(t)$ under the quotient map $F[t]\to F[t]/(f)$ is
>    $\overline {g(t)}$. This last one can be written as $$\overline
>  {g(t)}=\alpha_0\times \overline 1+\dots+\alpha_{n-1}\times
>  \overline{t^{n-1}}=\alpha_0\overline
>  1+\dots+\alpha_{n-1}\overline{t^{n-1}},$$ where I have used notation
>    ($\times$) from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722741/basis-for-rx-f-as-an-r-module). Further we can write
>    $$\overline{g(t)}=\overline {1\alpha_0 }+\dots+\overline {1
>  \alpha_{n-1}t^{n-1}}=\overline{1\alpha_0+\dots+1\alpha_{n-1}t^{n-1}}.$$
>    Consider the image of this element under the isomorphism $F[t]/(f)\to
>  W$. On the one hand, the image is $w$. On the other hand, since
>    $\overline 1$ maps to $w_0$, the image is $\alpha_0
>  w_0+\dots+\alpha_{n-1}t^{n-1}w_0$. So $w$ is the linear combination of
>    $(w_0,tw_0,\dots,t^{n-1}w_0)$ with coeffieients
>    $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n-1})$.

Proof of **independence**:

> Let $\alpha_0w_0+\alpha_1tw_0+\dots+\alpha_{n-1}t^{n-1}w_0=0$ in $W$. Then $p(t)=\alpha_0+\alpha_1t+\dots+\alpha_{n-1}t^{n-1}$ lies in the kernel of the map $F[t]\to W$ described above. So $f$ divides $p$ in $F[t]$: there is $q\in F[t]$ such that $p(t)=f(t)q(t)$. This is impossible unless all $\alpha_i$ are zero since $f$ is monic and hence $\deg p = n-1 < n = \deg f$. (See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2722757/333743).)

Comment: It seems like you're reproving the content of your previous question. As Artin writes, you have an isomorphism $F[t]/(f) \to W$ of $F[t]$-modules, which is also an isomorphism of $F$-vector spaces. Any isomorphism of $F$-vector spaces takes a basis of the domain to a basis of the codomain. In the previous question, you showed that $1, t, \ldots, t^{n-1}$ is a basis for $F[t]/(f)$, and the images of these vectors are precisely $w_{0}, tw_{0}, \ldots, t^{n-1}w_{0}$, since the isomorphism $F[t]/(f) \to W$ sends $1$ to $w_{0}$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thanks, I missed the fact that this isomorphism can be regarded as an isomorphism of vector spaces...

Comment: Happy to help! This stuff can be tricky. :)

Comment: @AlexWertheim Just to clarify: when Artin says that $(1,t,\dots,t^{n-1})$ is a basis of $F[t]/(f)$, this is not, strictly speaking, true, right? I think what he means is that $(\overline 1, \overline {t}, \dots, \overline {t^{n-1}})$ is a basis for $F[t]/(f)$. (Is this a typo or a jargon?)

Comment: Cary: yes, you're correct - a fair gripe. It's jargon as opposed to a typo - this kind of abuse of notation (identifying equivalence classes with their representatives) is not uncommon.